# How do I route the traffic on a SSID on my AP to a VLAN on my firewall?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, vlan, captive-portal

I have one firewall(pfsense) one AP(tomato) and 2 SSID,
Home users and guest users.

I want to set up a captive portal for guest users but I'm not sure how. 
How do I make it so that the guest SSID routess all connections to a vlan on my firewall and the captive portal applies to people on that vlan only? Do I need aditional hardware or can I do this with just one AP and one router?

Comment: Do you have an AP (rather than a wireless router) that you are running Tomato on? What is it? (I am curious because if I can get this hardware setup I may be able to deduce the software solution. Linux based systems can do VLAN tagging in software, generally.)

Comment: @edward my AP is my old wireless router. Net gear wndr3400v3